# Find missing dataframe elements not present in a given input list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

There is a user defined list `values = ['color','oilType','motor']` and a dataframe df having 15 columns including 'color' and 14 other column names. 'oilType' and 'motor' are not present in df. However on running the below snippet only 'motor' is getting outputted. The ideal output (missing columns in the df) should be 'oilType' and 'motor'

```
df = pd.read_csv('type.csv',sep=',',error_bad_lines=False)
targets=list(df.columns)
values = ['color','oilType','motor']
with open("source.txt", "w") as output:
    output.write(str(values))
with open('source.txt','r') as source:
    for source1 in values:
        source1 = source1.strip().lower()
    for target1 in targets:
        if source1 not in target1:
            with open("columns_missing.txt", "w") as output:
                output.write(str(source1))
```

what should be changed so that both 'oilType' and 'motor' are found as missing from the df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for loops should be nested and are not. When you iterate over `values` you're not doing anything with each value, you're simply ending on "motor". So by the time you start iterating on `targets` your `source1` variable is "motor" and doesn't change. Try indenting like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('type.csv',sep=',',error_bad_lines=False)
targets=list(df.columns)
values = ['color','oilType','motor']
with open("source.txt", "w") as output:
    output.write(str(values))
with open('source.txt','r') as source:
    for source1 in values:
        source1 = source1.strip().lower()
        for target1 in targets:
            if source1 not in target1:
                with open("columns_missing.txt", "w") as output:
                    output.write(str(source1))
```

In general, a better way to approach what you're doing will be to use the `difference` method of a set:

```
data = np.random.randint(50, size=20).reshape(5,4)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["A", "B", "C", "D"])

print(df)
    A   B   C   D
0  28  40  29  44
1  29   7  48  38
2  41   5  48  31
3  45  42  28  44
4   6  45  15  37

values = ["hello", "B", "world", "D"]
not_found = set(values).difference(df.columns)
print(not_found) # not_found == {"hello", "world"}

with open("columns_missing.txt", "w") as output:
    for value in not_found:
        output.write(value)
```

Comment: the difference method of a set ran perfectly..thanks a lot